# Request is missing required authentication credential - Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-play-developer-api

I want to refund to Google Play Developer Console IAP(In-App-Purchase) or order using Google API. I got an error when I hit their url, someone help me fix it.

**This is my code**

```
<?php
$url = "https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/orders/{orderId}:refund";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($server_output);
?>
```

**Responce**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "androidpublisher.googleapis.com",
          "method": "androidpublisher.OrdersService.Refund"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: _Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential_ So where is the authorisation code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have access token but I did not set it as authentication credential. You please tell me how I will set it access token as a authentication credential.

Comment: Is that your full code? Did you try to follow [this docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth)?